# Get Object and all its relations with Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have two database tables. One for saving basic data, and one for saving history of the data. As an example: I'm having a table `books` and a table `book_data`

Now, in the books table I have a column like `sales`. This is the number of sales generated for the book today. In the book_data I'm also saving the `sales` number but additionally add a date for this counting. So I can see, how many sales the book got over the last 7 days for example.

To get the book by ID I'm doing the following

```
try {
    $book = Book::findOrFail($id);
    return [
        'status'    => 'success',
        'data'      => $post
    ];
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return response()->json([
        'status'    => 'error',
        'data'      => 'No book with this id found'
    ], 400);
 }
```

But now, I also want to get the "history" of the sales. Meaning, when I select one book, I also want to get all related values from my `book_data` table. So, when I have saved data for the last 4 days, I want to also display this data in my response.

In my `Book` model class I have

```
public function history()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\\Models\\BookData');
}
```

I have already written this code, which basically works...

```
public function show($id)
{
    try {
        $post = Book::with('history')->get()->find($id);
        return [
            'status'    => 'success',
            'data'      => $post
        ];
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status'    => 'error',
            'data'      => 'No post with this id found'
        ], 400);
    }
}
```

...however, I have multiple issues with this solution.

1st: Isn't this bad for the performance, since I'm first getting all objects with their relation and **then afterwards** I filter it by id?
2nd: A `ModelNotFoundException` isn't thrown, when I'm passing an ID that doesn't exist.

So, how would I achieve this, the best way? Both for perfomance and readibilty and best case.

Comment: No need for `get()`. `$post = Book::with('history')->find($id);`

Comment: Thanks. This at least minfies the code. However, I'm still getting all posts and **THEN** am filtering, ain't I? Wouldn't my problem, that it isn't good for the performance not persist in this case? Also my `ModelNotFoundException` still wouldn't be fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's no need for `get()`. You can use `find()` on it's own:

```
$post = Book::with('history')->find($id);
```

This **does not** query all records and filter afterwards. It basically just adds a WHERE clause for the id and returns the first (and only) result.

---

The `ModelNotFoundException` is only thrown if you use `findOrFail()`. `find()` will just return `null`. So this is what you want:

```
$post = Book::with('history')->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: That was easy. Guess I was confused, since I couldn't use `findOrFail` after using `get`. However, I can use `findOrFail` if I ommit the `get` method, which is, as you saidn, not needed. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `findOrFail()` because after calling `get()` you have a collection which doesn't have that method...